# Blackboard bold, once again

Tags: mathbb

I'm looking for a way to produce a blackboard bold version of numbers - not just 1 or 2, all of them. I've tried bbm:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{bbm}

\begin{document}
    $\mathbbm{1}$\\
    $\mathbbm{2}$\\
    $\mathbbm{3}$\\
    $\mathbbm{4}$\\
    $\mathbbm{5}$\\
    $\mathbbm{6}$\\
    $\mathbbm{7}$\\
    $\mathbbm{8}$\\
    $\mathbbm{9}$\\
    $\mathbbm{0}$\\
\end{document}
```

But this only works for 1 and 2. How can I get the other numbers in a good quality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another package could be `mathalfa` with option `bb=boondox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[bb=boondox]{mathalfa}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{1},\mathbb{2}, \mathbb{3}, \mathbb{4}, \mathbb{5}, \mathbb{6}, \mathbb{7}, \mathbb{8}, \mathbb{9}, \mathbb{10}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful - thx

Comment: @j4nd3r53n Also the stix font are beautiful :-) of the David's answer. I use often `mathalfa`. Thank you very much for to have appreciate my answer.

Answer (score 1):

several fonts have these, eg stix

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}
    $\mathbb{1}$

    $\mathbb{2}$

    $\mathbb{3}$

    $\mathbb{4}$

    $\mathbb{5}$

    $\mathbb{6}$

    $\mathbb{7}$

    $\mathbb{8}$

    $\mathbb{9}$

    $\mathbb{0}$

\end{document}
```